# How do I extract the data from the URL using Regex (Know the variable name)?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract data from a website https://www.icra.in/Rationale/Index?CompanyName=20%20Microns%20Limited using Scrapy and Beautiful Soup. However, both scrapers return empty when I use the class `'list-nw'`.

I tried different parsers using BS but the same. On closer look, I noticed the [view source](http://view-source:https://www.icra.in/Rationale/Index?CompanyName=20%20Microns%20Limited) has the data I need. Thus I get the page content in text which has the data. (rather than the class).

How do I extract the entire array using Regex for the key `"LstrationaleDetails"` inside variable `var Model`. (Line number 793)?

I tried several Regex but was unable to. Is Regex the only option or I can use Scrapy or BS? Also confused as after extracting how will I store it? If it was a JSON I could de-serialize it. I was thinking of something in lines of `split` and `eval`.

I tried this for BS.

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib.parser')
print(soup)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, I think regex is the only option since html parsers don't 'understand' Js code. It seems the `Model` variable is valid json that can be passed to `json.loads()`

Comment: I am trying to find a suitable regex to extract the variable. Can you help with that? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, try: `'var Model =(.*?);\s+Ratinoal'` and use the DOTALL  or MULTILINE flag.

Comment: Trying on https://regex101.com/ and unable to find the DOTALL flag. Also tried with the python re. Also ``` data = re.findall("var Model =(.+?);\n", response.body.decode("utf-8"), re.S) ``` Something is wrong in my RE.

Comment: I was able to extract the data with the following line: `data = re.search('var Model =(.*?);\s+Ratinoal', s, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)`. Where `s` is the html response.

Comment: @t.m.adam That should be an answer :-)

Comment: Please type it as an answer so I that I can put it as 'Correct'. Thanks, both worked and I have learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: QHarr and Dinesh Yes you're right, but I don't have time to post a full answer, I was just playing with the URL. @QHarr you can answer this if you want.

Comment: I am happy to post a wiki and attribute to you. I would also happily upvote a quick answer from you that would literally be copy pasta of your comments.  You essentially are doing a variation on data = re.search('var Model =(.*?);\s+Ratinoal', str(soup.select_one('html')), flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)

Comment: @QHarr If you can post an answer that would be great; this is a decent question. And you don't need BeautifulSoup here, you can just use the full html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributable to @t.m.adam

You can use the following regex to extract from source html. Use the  [DOTALL flag](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to allow for newlines. User-Agent is required in headers.

```
import requests
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.icra.in/Rationale/Index?CompanyName=20%20Microns%20Limited'
headers = {    
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
data = re.search('var Model =(.*?);\s+Ratinoal', r.text, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
result = json.loads(data)
for item in result['LstrationaleDetails']:
    print(item)
```

Comment: @t.m.adam Be sure to drop me a line here when you have time for a full answer and I will delete this.